# Angular-Maps. How to load all markers in all browsers before the map loads?

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, meteor

**Issue:**

I'm attempting to place 1369 map markers on an `angular-map` before it loads and I am having consistency issues.  Half the time the map loads all 1369, the other half a random number will load.

**Map.js**

```
    angular.module('dogMap')
    .controller('MapCtrl', function($scope, $meteor, uiGmapGoogleMapApi) {
      uiGmapGoogleMapApi.then(function(maps) {
        var dogParks = $meteor.collection(DogParks);

        $scope.map = {
          zoom: 4,
          bounds: {},
          center: {
            latitude: 40.1451,
            longitude: -99.6680
          }
        };

        function assignMarkersToMap() {
          markers = [];
          for (var i=0; i < (dogParks.length - 1); i++) {
            markers.push({
              latitude: dogParks[i].latitude,
              longitude: dogParks[i].longitude,
              title: dogParks[i].name,
              id: dogParks[i]._id,
              icon: "https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript
                     /examples/full/images/beachflag.png"
            });
          };
          return markers;
        };

        $scope.markers = [];
        // Get the bounds from the map once it's loaded
        $scope.$watch(function() {
          return $scope.map.bounds;
        }, function(nv, ov) {
          // Only need to regenerate once
          if (!ov.southwest && nv.southwest) {
            var markers = []
            $scope.markers = assignMarkersToMap();
          }
        }, true);

        $scope.markerCount = function() {
          console.log($scope.markers.length);
        };


        $scope.windowCoords = {};
        $scope.parkName = "cool";

        $scope.onClick = function(marker, eventName, model) {
            $scope.map.center.latitude = model.latitude;
            $scope.map.center.longitude = model.longitude;
            $scope.map.zoom = 11;
            $scope.windowCoords.latitude = model.latitude;
            $scope.windowCoords.longitude = model.longitude;
            $scope.parkName = model.title;
            $scope.show = true;
        };

        $scope.closeClick = function() {
            $scope.show = false;
        };

        $scope.options = {
          scrollwheel: false
        };

        $scope.show = false;

      });
    });
```

**map.html**

```
<h1>Testing Map View</h1>

<div id="map_canvas">
  <ui-gmap-google-map center="map.center" zoom="map.zoom" draggable="false" 
                      options="options" bounds="map.bounds" control="googlemap">
      <ui-gmap-markers models="markers" coords="'self'" icon="'icon'" 
                       options="'options'" doRebuildAll="true" click="onClick">
        <ui-gmap-window show="show" coords='windowCoords' closeClick="closeClick()">
            <div>{{parkName}}</div>
        </ui-gmap-window>
      </ui-gmap-markers>
  </ui-gmap-google-map>
</div>

<button ng-click="markerCount();">Marker Count</button>
```

Comment: It would help to have a working fiddle of the current working code

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the main issue (from performance perspective) in the provided example is related with info windows, instead of creating info window per every marker you could create a *single instance* of info window to share across all the markers.

As a small improvement, for waiting until map is ready, instead of  `$watch` you could utilize `uiGmapIsReady` service.

**Example**

The example shows how to render `1000` markers:

```js
angular.module('dogMap', ['uiGmapgoogle-maps'])
    .controller('MapCtrl', function($scope, uiGmapGoogleMapApi,uiGmapIsReady) {
      uiGmapGoogleMapApi.then(function(maps) {
        //var dogParks = $meteor.collection(DogParks);
        var dogParks = genarateDogParks(1000);

        $scope.map = {
          zoom: 4,
          bounds: {},
          center: {
            latitude: 40.1451,
            longitude: -99.6680
          }
        };

        function assignMarkersToMap() {
          markers = [];
          for (var i=0; i < dogParks.length; i++) {
            markers.push({
              latitude: dogParks[i].latitude,
              longitude: dogParks[i].longitude,
              title: dogParks[i].name,
              id: dogParks[i]._id,
              icon: "https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/beachflag.png"
            });
          };
          return markers;
        };

        $scope.markers = [];
        
        
        uiGmapIsReady.promise()                    
        .then(function(instances) {           
           $scope.markers = assignMarkersToMap();
        });
 

        $scope.windowCoords = {};

        $scope.onClick = function(marker, eventName, model) {
            $scope.map.center.latitude = model.latitude;
            $scope.map.center.longitude = model.longitude;
            $scope.map.zoom = 11;
            $scope.windowCoords.latitude = model.latitude;
            $scope.windowCoords.longitude = model.longitude;
            $scope.parkName = model.title;
            $scope.show = true;
        };

        $scope.closeClick = function() {
            $scope.show = false;
        };

        $scope.options = {
          scrollwheel: false
        };

        $scope.show = false;

      });
    });


function genarateDogParks(count){
    var vals = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        vals.push({
            latitude: getRandomArbitrary(33.192528,48.209871),
            longitude: getRandomArbitrary(-118.586462,-81.716346),
            _id: i,
            name: 'Dog Park #' + i     
        });     
    }
    return vals;    
}    


function getRandomArbitrary(min, max) {
    return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}
```

```css
.angular-google-map-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.14/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/2.4.1/lodash.js"></script>
<script src="http://rawgit.com/angular-ui/angular-google-maps/2.0.X/dist/angular-google-maps.js"></script>
<div ng-app="dogMap" ng-controller="MapCtrl">
  <ui-gmap-google-map center="map.center" zoom="map.zoom" draggable="false" 
                      options="options" bounds="map.bounds" control="googlemap">
      <ui-gmap-window show="show" coords='windowCoords' closeClick="closeClick()">
            <div>{{parkName}}</div>
      </ui-gmap-window>                
      <ui-gmap-markers models="markers" coords="'self'" icon="'icon'" 
                       options="'options'" doRebuildAll="true" click="onClick">
      </ui-gmap-markers>
  </ui-gmap-google-map>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vgrem/2vLsyphq/1/) that demonstrates how to render `3000` objects on map

Comment: Hey Vadim, Thanks for the response.  I tried putting the **assignMarkersToMap()** function into the **uiGmapIsReady.promise()**, but it didn't help load the markers any faster.  I also tried your example of creating markers at random locations and it worked fine with 3000 objects...  I'm beginning to think that looping through the collection and putting info into the markers array is taking too long and doesn't load fast enough some of the time. Note: When I add a click button to push the markers into the markers array it works fine after the page is loaded.

Comment: Joseph, maybe i was not clear enough, but the improvement related with creating a **single** instance of info window (`ui-gmap-window` directive) is more important than utilizing  `uiGmapIsReady`  service